# How to use joomla root url in it's Backend text editor?

Tags: url, joomla, root

I would like to use site root url in one of my backend custom HTML module. Is there any way to write php code in backend editor ? like this

```
echo   JUri::root().'test/test.html';
```

Or any way to find site url from backend text editor.

I have root directory on my local site as like this : localhost/maf/modernartframing/

But live :

www.modernartframing.com/

Comment: No, you can't do this in Joomla's text editors. You need to use an extension such as Sourcerer

Answer (score 1):

There are two extensions that may be are good for you.

[jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jumi) it allows you to call php script in you page content and modules

[DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/directphp) it allows you to directly insert php code

Btw probably for you it's better to just generate a new menu with the link you want and after make a module for that menu.